Is there a way how to refetch data after deleting a row from table using TanStack table with React?
I'm building a web application using Spring boot and React, with React I'm using @tanstack/react-table library to create a generic table Table.tsx to manage any type of data.
In my CategoryList.tsx, each time I delete a row from the category list, I perform a DELETE request to the server and then I filter the state to remove the row based on rowIndex which works fine. the issue is whenever I navigate to other components (ex: Dashboard.tsx) and go back to CategoryList.tsx, it shows me data with the recently deleted row.

You need to provide more code to debug the issue.
But the core issue is related to only updating the derived state. You are probabally updating the wrong array state containing category list.
